# ensuring an async thread runs on the ui thread

Tags: java, android

I have objects (not on the ui thread) that need to run the async task as internal methods and I want to pass the ui thread to the method and then implement the ui thread on the asynctask that way - is there a way of doing this?

pseudo-code:

```
      public class EditDetails extends Activity{          
                MyObject obj = new obj;
                obj.syncWithServer(EditDetails.this);
      }

      public class MyObject {
           public void syncWithWerver(EditDetails parent){
                 final class GetUserHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Boolean /* Progress */, String /* Result */> {
                        @Override
                        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
                             return "";
                        }
                        @Override
                        protected String onPostExecute(String result) {
                              //this doesn't run
                        }
                 }
           }
      }
```

note: at the moment this isn't working because onPostExecute isn't firing after the doInBackground

**EDIT**

this code is pseudocode the actual problem is still happening and I have listed it http://pastebin.com/jW6JpUbg [here](http://pastebin.com/jW6JpUbg).. basically it gets stuck after running  line 72 on the pastebin in never does onPostExecute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you tried executing your task like this ?

```
parent.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            new GetUserHttpTask().execute();
        }
});
```

I think this should work..

**Added:**

Your [`AsyncTask`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html) implementation should be as below : 
Note : Read the updated comments

```
class GetUserHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String/* in parameter for doInBackground */, Boolean /* in parameter for onProgressUpdate */, String /* Out parameter and in parameter for onPostExecute method*/> {
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
        return "";
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        // this doesn't run
    }

    @Override
    protected void onProgressUpdate(Boolean... values) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    }
}
```

Comment: You should change the return type of your `onPostExecute` method as Boris mentioned and try the above code snippet. It should work.

Comment: I have added this snippet - I have not been able to get onPostExecute to run but the result is happening in doInBackground so it's ok I ran it manually from there using a "ok" code in the result response

Answer (score 2):

Weird enough the [`onPostExecute`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html#onPostExecute%28Result%29) should be `void`. I wonder how is your code compiling as you have changed the return type of overridden method?

After you correct your `onPostExecute` you can get the `AsyncTask` run as follows:

```
final class GetUserHttpTask extends AsyncTask<String/* Param */, Boolean /* Progress */, String /* Result */> {
        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
             return "";
        }
        @Override
        protected String onPostExecute(String result) {
              // this will run
        }
} 
public void syncWithWerver(EditDetails parent){
     AsyncTask task = new GetUserHttpTask();
     task.execute();
}
```

Comment: @PareshMayani nope, the method always returns void. The parameter type is changed

Comment: @Perception I would have posted it as a comment if I did not thought this is the key of solving the problem overall. Basically he does not declare `onPostExecute` correctly and so it is not fired.

Comment: @PareshMayani Yes @Boris is correct. Return type of `onPostExecute` should be `void`. The result type `String` is for `doInBackground` method not for `onPostExecute` method

Comment: yeah sorry it did return `void` it was a typo

Comment: @user2083181 I have added additional suggestion in my answer

Comment: Boris I have editted my post to link to the actual Java code and it is  showing no `onPostExecute` at line 72 (line 72 runs fine)

Comment: @user2083181: don't publish progress in `onPostExecute` see if the log message is printed then.